# How can I make this count characters insted of words

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How can I make this code count characters instead of words.

Thanks

```
function word_count(){
    text_value=CKEDITOR.instances.text_editor_name.getData();
    var matches = text_value.replace(/<[^<|>]+?>| /gi,' ').match(/\b/g);
    var count = 0;
    if(matches) {
        count = matches.length/2;
    }
    document.getElementById("word_count").innerHTML=count+" words";
}
```

Comment: You want to count only characters in words or all characters like whitespaces?

Comment: See those two CKEditor plugins ([1](http://ckeditor.com/addon/wordcount), [2](http://ckeditor.com/addon/stat)) to find the optimal implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this - 
`text_value.length`

Modified your function -

```
function word_count(){
    text_value=CKEDITOR.instances.text_editor_name.getData();
    document.getElementById("word_count").innerHTML=text_value.length+" words";
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use split strings have length too.

Comment: oops, Why did i do this. Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside this function, you can use `text_value.length;` instead of what's being used now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. When I add var matches = text_value.length; the value I am getting is NaN. Am I suppose to replace something else

Comment: You should leave the first line, as that fills the text_value with the actual text_value of your CKEditor. Right after the first line you can `return text_value.length;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the length of the string. Assuming you are counting after you have replaced characters then..

```
var count= text_value.replace(/<[^<|>]+?>| /gi,' ').match(/\b/g);
var result = count.length;

document.getElementById("word_count").innerHTML=result +" characters";
```

Taken from http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/string-length-method.php

Comment: You'd need to remove the `.match()` part too.  Note also that that JS "tutorial" is very low quality given that it describes `.length` as both a method and a function (when it is neither) and says that the result will be of variable type "integer" when actually it will be "number" (though of course the number will be an integer).

Comment: I agree with nnnnnnn the best personally I would add a bit to the code and do the replacement first then change the var name to 'something else' as it also makes checking easier.

Comment: _"personally I would add a bit to the code"_ - But this is your answer, so why didn't you include that in the answer? What I'm saying is that your answer doesn't work. `.match()` returns an array or `null`, not a string.

Comment: After I removed the .match() from the code it is almost working...for some reason it adds 1 more to the count than what is actually there. Any suggestions

Comment: Try adding a trim around your string before it comes in, it can be as simple as that.

Comment: Trim is not working for me so I added count.length -1 and it works when it is counting but a -1 shows up first and i would like to have a 0 show up instead

Comment: What happens if you remove you replace function?